# VMWare esxi 4.1 storage errors with MD3200

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

We're seeing some storage errors from the esxi logs relating to our MD3200. I'm sort of a VMWare noob and am not sure where to go from here because I couldn't find a lot of documentation on the VMWare website, and the forums didn't seem to have any posts about it with actual answers. Everything is working, but I'm trying to proactively troubleshoot this.

```
sfcb-vmware_base|StoragePool Cannot get logical disk data from controller 0
sfcb-vmware_base|Volume Cannot get logical disk data from controller 0
sfcb-vmware_base|storelib-GetLDList-ProcessLibCommandCall failed; rval = 0x800E
```

The ESXi boxes are connected directly via SAS to the controller on the MD3200.

What do these errors actually mean, and what's a good path to start troubleshooting or solving them?

Answer (score 1):

According to [THIS](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1030817) VMWare KB article you can ignore these.

Comment: "While running boothalt stress test with rhel5.4-64bit (16GB, 8 vcpu) and memtest1 (16GB, 6vcpu), you see these messages repeated in /var/log/messages:" -- that doesn't apply to my situation. Neither does "This issue occurs if you install the Thin .iso VMware-VMvisor-Installer-4.0.0.Update02-228629.x86_64.iso on ESX 4.0 Update 2".